# How to set file highlight color in project tree with plugin DevKit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide

How to set file highlight color in project tree with plugin DevKit?
I am developing plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, 
now I have found out how to get color of selected file:

```
   final Project currentProject = DataKeys.PROJECT.getData(anActionEvent.getDataContext()); 
   VirtualFile[] currentFiles = DataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE_ARRAY.getData(anActionEvent.getDataContext()); 
   if(currentFiles != null) { 
      Arrays.asList(currentFiles).forEach(virtualFile -> { 
      FileColorManager colorManager = FileColorManager.getInstance(currentProject); 
      Color color = colorManager.getFileColor(virtualFile); 
      } 
   }
```

But how to SET color of selected file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an extension point `com.intellij.ide.projectView.TreeStructureProvider` that would return custom implementations of `com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiFileNode` where you can modify displayed text/color/icon...

Please note that file's VCS status by default will override presentation (`com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeNode#setForcedForeground`).

Comment: I can't find in which method should I return custom implementation of PsiFileNode.There is three methods `modify`, `getData` and `isDumbAware`
And I can't find method `setForcedForeground` in `AbstractTreeNode` class.

Comment: Please use `modify()`, Javadoc has all details and look at implementations in IJ Community sources.`setForcedForeground` may simply not be available in the platform version you're targeting.